# What is shared across hardcore characters in my account?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just created a new character and I noticed he has 10k of gold, by going into the AH, without even logging on. Are items collected by any of my HC characters kept in my account's stash in case I die? Is the same true for gold or is this some kind of bug?

This is quite important since all that's with the character is lost when he dies.

Also, what of artisans' progress?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences between Hardcore and Normal heroes](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66173/differences-between-hardcore-and-normal-heroes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hardcore works the same as normal mode in terms of what is shared. This includes at least: gold, artisan progress and anything in your stash as well as stash size unlocked. These things just aren't shared between hardcore and normal mode.

No items on your character or in their inventory at the time of death is saved. Gold is special in that you can't 'store' it as such and so any gold you have accumulated is saved.

Comment: So your artisan progress and everything in your stash are saved to if you die (if I've inferred correctly from your answer)?

Comment: @JamesJiao: I believe so, but I honestly haven't upgraded my artisans at all in Hardcore yet. I usually favor buying stuff from the AH.

Comment: @JamesJiao: My understanding of the situation is that HC and normal mode are exactly the same except death is permanent. To help prevent hoarding in normal and making HC too easy, they've totally separated the two modes (AH, everything), but there is nothing functionally different other than the permanent death.

Comment: @JamesJiao: Yes artisan progress is saved in HC

Answer (score 2):

Artisan progress, gold, and items in your shared stash are shared between HC characters.